# Is Parcelable faster than Serializable for HashMap

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap, parcelable, serializable

In Android, `Parcelable` is supposed to be much faster than `Serializable`. However `HashMap` is not a `Parcelable`, we can still make it `Parcelable` if our key/value are primitive types or `Parcelable`, like this:

```
class MyParcelableMap() : HashMap<Int, String>(), Parcelable {

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
        val keys = parcel.createIntArray() ?: IntArray(0)
        val values = parcel.createStringArray() ?: emptyArray<String>()
        keys.forEachIndexed {i, k ->
            this[k] = values[i]
        }
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        val entries = this.entries
        val keys = entries.map { it.key }.toIntArray()
        val values = entries.map { it.value }.toTypedArray()
        parcel.writeIntArray(keys)
        parcel.writeStringArray(values)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelableMap> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): MyParcelableMap {
            return MyParcelableMap(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<MyParcelableMap?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Since we will manually read/write each entry, I'm not sure this will be faster than `Serializable`, assuming `Serializable` will just reconstruct the map without adding entries one by one.

If `Parcelable` is not faster, then there is no benefit to do this, we can just pass the `Map<Int, String>` as `Serializable`, no additional code needed. So I want to know is `Parcelable` faster in this case or not, or maybe it depends on the map size.